# Rotina Automatica AspNet Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lógica

Eu tenho a classe **ClienteEmpresa** e a classe **ArquivosFiscais**
um **cliente** tem um lista de **arquivos fiscais** (no máximo 12 por ano, sendo uma de cada mês) e um **ArquivoFiscal** tem um Cliente.

```
public class ArquivosFiscais
{
     public virtual ClienteEmpresa ClienteEmpresa { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClienteEmpresa")]
        public int IdClienteEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Preciso criar uma rotina, que seja startada automaticamente, sem a interação do usuário, no primeiro dia de cada mês. e preciso que ela seja Stardata, apenas uma unica vez todo mês. preciso criar um **arquivo** para cada **cliente**

Então criei esse método..(não sei se a lógica está certa).

```
private Contexto db = new Contexto();

        public void CriarArquivoPrimeiroDiaDeCadaMes()
        {
            DateTime data = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime primeiroDiaDoMes = new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, 1);
            if (data == new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, 1))
            {
                var cliente = db.ClienteEmpresaDb.Where(c => c.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Ativo || c.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Bloqueado);
                foreach (var item in cliente)
                {
                    using (var sal = new Contexto())
                    {
                        ArquivosFiscais af = new ArquivosFiscais();
                        af.DataAbertura = DateTime.Now;
                        af.DataDoEnvio = null;
                        af.IdClienteEmpresa = item.Id;
                        af.StatusArquivo = Smc.Dominio.Model.ArquivosFiscais.StatusArquivo.NaoEnviado;
                        af.MesDeReferencia = new DateTime(data.Month);
                        sal.ArquivosFiscaisDb.Add(af);
                        sal.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Não sei se a lógica está certa.. como eu faço para esse método ser iniciado automaticamente?

Comment: Como o seu sistema é web aconselho você fazer sua rotina no banco através de algum job, ou senão usar o algum `schedule` com o HangFire: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Também recomendaria o HangFire

Comment: Foi a melhor opção, HangFire, é uma mão na roda, eu não conhecia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de algum scheduler, dentre as várias opções destaco 2 que já utilizei:

1. **Hangfire** (a mais comum) https://hangfire.io
   O Hangfire é muito completo para execução de tarefas do tipo chame e esqueça (fire & forget), muito utilizado para executar tarefas fora da thread do usuário. Pode ser utilizado com a finalidade de executar um processo de acordo com um agendamento (1x por dia, 1x por mes etc) mas o foco dele não é este. Ele cria uma base de dados própria onde armazena os as tarefas agendadas e conta com um dashboard para verificar o estado da cada execução. Por ser muito completo e precisar de criar um banco de dados, eu costumo utiliza-lo somente quando meu sistema vai ter muita comunicação com serviços de terceiros, envios de e-mail, processos longos etc. Ele brilha nesta parte.
2. **Quartz** (a mais simples) https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/
   Esta é a mais simples de implementar, a sua própria aplicação é o scheduler e não requer uma base de dados. Para agendar tarefas que ocorrem de tempos em tempos, eu geralmente utilizo ele. Não tem dashboard, não tem estado, mas funciona...